# sitemaps on cross submits

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I went through the following link http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html for sitemaps & cross submits but did not get clarification if the following approach is correct or not:

I've the following websites one for desktop users and other for mobile users both server different content:
`https://www.mainsite.com` and `https://mobile.site.com` both domains point to same website physical root directory and based on user's device the domain URL is changed.

I've placed a robots.txt file in this root directory which has an entry to sitemap_index.xml file:

```
sitemap: https://www.mainsite.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

In sitemap_index file

```
    <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
    <loc>
     https://www.mainsite.com/sitemap_desktop_www.xml
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2015-09-04</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
    <loc>
    https://mobile.site.com/sitemap_mobile_www.xml
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2015-05-22</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    </sitemapindex>
```

Is this approach correct?

If a bot reads robots.txt and sitemap_index.xml file for domain `www.mainsite.com` and in sitemap_index.xml will it ignore `mobile.site.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your two websites in Google webmaster as two properties and in each one you can add your XML sitemap without the need for the robots.txt

Google will start crawling and indexing your website and see your XML sitemap for each domain.